# Webpack: Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'postcss'

Tags: css, typescript, webpack, sass, loader

I am trying to integrate my webpack project with sass-loader, but I am get this error:

```
 Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'postcss'
```

I already installed postcss and postcss-loader with command:

```
 npm install postcss postcss-loader --save-dev
```

After install, I continue to get the same error message. I test integrate my project only with css-loader and the same error occurs. I think postcss is a dependency of the css-loader.

In my webpack.config.js I use this configuration in my module.rules:

```
 {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [{
          loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
      }, {
          loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
      }, {
          loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
      }
    ]
  }
```

I installed all this loaders and node-sass, I don't know what I am doing wrong :(

Comment: Execute `npm install postcss --save-dev`. It should resolve your issues.

Comment: I install postcss, but error continues.

Comment: Seems strange to me, `sass-loader` only require `node-sass` to be installed as peerDependency. You don't need `postcss` to use `sass-loader`. Anyway, try to install both `postcss` and `postcss-loader` with `npm install --save-dev postcss postcss-loader`, and try to add `{loader: "postcss-loader"}` in **between** your `sass-loader` and `css-loader`.

Comment: I try to execute my project in a linux machine and I don't have any problems. For some reason in my windows machine I always get this error. I verify in my node_modules/postcss only have these files: _node_modules_ and _package.info_. It is like modules not installed correctly.

Comment: On Windows try to delete your *node_modules* && *package-lock.json* and then run `npm install` to re-install all packages.

Comment: I delete node_modules and package-lock.json, but still get the error.

Answer (score 21):

I had this error when using autoprefixer with postcss through postcss-cli. I solved it by rolling postcss back to version 8.1.0 (current version is 8.1.1 at time of writing). This can be easily done by running the below command in your terminal.

```
npm i postcss@8.1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

**Use the following steps**

Delete package-lock.json

Delete node_modules

Run npm install

Answer (score 2):

In my case problem was solved by delete **package.lock**.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading `postcss-cli` to the new version `9.0.1` fixed it for me.